# Getting certain information from magento's mage.php file

Tags: php, html, magento, e-commerce, web-development-server

I wonder if any of you could help?!

I've recently started a new project which requires an e-commerce system, with that being said I have installed magento and have started to play around with it.... however I am struggling to find any sort of information on using the mage.php file.

What I need really is help on the list below...

1. I've been looking for the code to display a product from magento on a page that is not situated within magento's platform. Can anyway point me to the code needed for this please
2. I'd like to incorporate the checkout/login or logout/my account links on every page even when not viewing a page located in magentos system.

I suppose basically I want to use magento to handle the product side of things but want to create my website without having to touch magento except from to call in certain functions.

Any help on this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can build the website using an easier content management system such as Wordpress and only use Magento for the Shop section of the website.

There is a plugin for Wordpress that allows you to display products from a Magent website.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/magento/

Comment: Hmmm ok I will look into this, the only annoying thing I kinda wanted to stay away from wordpress and do it myself but thanks :)

Comment: Yeah I understand. Wordpress is just one of the solutions that you can choose. You could opt to create pages in Magento but in my experience they are difficult to customize. Wordpress is just an easier way to customize them. It does have drawbacks e.g. having a second CMS system to log into.